# can i have a multi class selector in jquery

Tags: jquery

Can I do something like the below where I can have multiple classes trigger an event?

```
$('a.red a.blue a.green').click(function(event) 
{

});
```

Comment: Just a note for the OP: Classes are defined by `.` not `:`. `:` denotes pseudo-classes.

Comment: Related note: the syntax you have there (`a.red a.blue a.green`) has a different meaning as a css and jquery selector. It selects any `a` element with a class of `green` that's contained in an `a` element with a class of `blue`, which is itself contained in an `a` element with a class of `red`. of course, this makes no sense when they're all `a` tags, but it *is* a useful concept in general.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, you can use the comma as separator.

```
$('a.red, a.blue, a.green').click(function(event) {});
```

Answer (score 3):

A slightly different approach would be to prefix your classes like `a.prefix_red`, `a.prefix_blue`, `a.prefix_green` and then use a wildcard selector on it like:

```
$("a[class^=prefix_]")
```

The advantage is that as long as you prefix all your "trigger" classes, you don't have to edit the jQuery every time you add a new one, not that it would be a major edit anyways, but might come in handy if you decide to minify your script for example.

Answer (score 0):

`$('a.red.blue.green')` selects the elements that have **all** those classes.

`$('a.red, a.blue, a.green')` selects the elements that have **atleast one** of those classes.

Comment: For all those classes, it is $("a.red.blue.green").